# Symbian development in Java

Tags: java, java-me, symbian

I have found that development for Symbian is possible in C++ with Qt, but since its a project that needs to be developed for Symbian+Android, I don't want to spend time learning C++, since I'm into Java/Android only.

I have downloaded the Symbian SDK from Nokia site, and can make Midlets and test them on a Symbian emulator. But I have doubt that the J2ME library can keep up with Android, and support the same features.

Is there possibly an extended Java SDK for smartphones, or are there other possibilities developing for Symbian with Java?
Also, there is very little information or tutorials for Symbian development, but still it has a big share in smartphone market, which is confusing.

Comment: Symbian is very much on its way to the grave. Nokia is migrating. The effort necessary to support Symbian is really not worth it.

Comment: There are 100's of millions of Symbian devices out there!

Comment: @James But most of those 100M+ aren't on smartphones, and the Symbian smartphones that are in the wild are not usually used as modern "app" phones.

Comment: Symbian devices have been able to do for years what iPhone/Android can do now

Comment: Update: Nokia will be switching to [MeeGo](https://meego.com/). Their latest phone, [Nokia N9](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_n9-3398.php) will come with MeeGo 1.2.

Comment: Nokia are switching to Windows Phone. The N9 will be the last MeeGo device (until WP flops and they need to switch back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Radu said: don't bother. Symbian is like a person in the middle of the desert who's been bitten by a poisonous snake. *Technically*, he's not dead yet, but he will be soon, as there's no help, so he's *practically* dead.

Would you develop for Windows 95/98/ME or OS/2 or Mac OS 9? Of course not, unless you had to (i.e. someone's paying you to). Don't bother developing for Symbian unless you're specifically getting paid to.

---

To answer the question you asked:

J2ME is clunky and missing tons of features. It almost definitely won't keep pace with Android-Java. In college (fairly recently), I took a mobile design class that used Nokia/Symbian because they were willing to provide free phones to test on (N95s). We used J2ME because the professor didn't want to learn the Symbian C frameworks (probably a good decision), but J2ME on Symbian is very limited, slow, and very obviously designed for the least common denominator. It'll be just as different from Android-Java as if you were programming in Symbian C.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting paid for it, cause Symbian has a market share of 30% if i'm not mistaken. I am developing the app as JQuery mobile page, I guess that makes my situation better, cause JQuery is platform-independent? But still, how do I export it to Symbian?

Comment: Can you at least target the more-recent versions of Symbian that have Webkit browsers? That would make adaptation easier (practically nonexistent), as at most you'd have a wrapper for the page, or ask users to browse to the site.

Comment: The site is local, so are the libraries, css, etc.

Comment: Then you're beyond my knowledge level. Good luck. You may want to ask a new question along the lines of "How do I present a local webpage to a user on Symbian, preferably in J2ME?" to get more-specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

To pick up on this comment:

> Unfortunately I am getting paid for it, cause Symbian has a market
>   share of 30% if i'm not mistaken. I am developing the app as JQuery
>   mobile page, I guess that makes my situation better, cause JQuery is
>   platform-independent? But still, how do I export it to Symbian?

You might consider using the [Symbian Web Runtime (WRT)](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Category%3aSymbian_Web_Runtime) which [works with jQuery](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Simple_Web_Runtime_Design_Patterns_Using_jQuery). If the functionality you need is covered by what you can do in HTML/CSS/Javacript, then it is a good choice - there are a wealth of code examples on the Nokia site. In effect, you use a 'local page' to make the app.